# R coding for random value with contraint

Tags: r

I want to know R code for generating 1000 random values for x and y between 1 to 7 such that x<=y and all the numbers are identically distributed.

Comment: what about  `runif(1000, min = 1, max = 7)`

Comment: Hi, Thanks! but I want two columns x & y with 1000 rows containing intergers between 1 to 7 s.t. x <= y.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With float number

```
x <- c()
y <- c()
  for (i in 1:1000){
      x[i] <- runif(1, 1, 7)
      y[i] <- runif(1, x[i], 7)
     // print or do something you want here
    }
```

With integer number

```
x <- c()
y <- c()
for (i in 1:1000){
      x[i] <- sample(1:7, 1)
      y[i] <- sample(x[i]:7, 1)
     // print or do something you want here
    }
```

You can try it.

Comment: I think that could work.. I will try doing some editing here.. In case it doesn't, I will get back to you. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @LAP thanks for your editing, now its better than mine.

Comment: I would initialize the result vectors with `x <- numeric(1000)` or `integer(1000)`.

Comment: @LAP thanks, but it's still not working for when x is taking value 7. Do you have anything more to add?

Comment: x <- c()
y <- c()
for (i in 1:1000){
      x[i] <- sample(1:7, 1)
if(x[i]==7)
{
y[i]<-7
}
else
{
      y[i] <- sample(x[i]:7, 1)
}
     // print or do something you want here
    }

Comment: I couldnt edit above of code to become easily to view, but you should have an if else statement, when x = 7 then y =7 too, else y=sample(x:7,1)

Comment: It worked, Thanks!